# hydraulic diameter

Tags: fluid-mechanics, dynamics, hydraulics

QUESTION:[image]

I needed help here, I tried solving but still can't prove or arrive at the conclusion.

my working: [image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the correct answer, you just haven't simplified the terms.

Root 3 divided by 3 is 1 over root 3.

ie. x^(1/2)  / x = x^(1/2).x(-1) = x^(-1/2)

Comment: how do i show that root 3 divided 3 is 1 over root 3?

Comment: Look at the equation I provided, it's simply high school mathematics. Also, see [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(1%2F2)+%2F+x+%3D+x%5E(1%2F2).x(-1)+%3D+x%5E(-1%2F2)).